# Read comment attachment name and file location

Tags: views, entities, 9

I have a view that has comment, comment attachment(as a file). I want to read the file name and it's location. View looks like below:

[image]

I am able to read the title by the below code:

```
 public function execute(ContentEntityInterface $entity = NULL) {
    // publish the selected comment
    $entity->setPublished(TRUE)->save();

    //Read all the fields from entity
    $comment = $entity->get('comment_body')->getValue();
      //dd($comment); //throws comment title correctly
    $attachment = $entity->get('field_attachment')->getFileName();
      //dd($attachment); //errors at getFileName() function
}
```

I want to get the filename and file path. How to achieve it?

Comment: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21src%21Entity%21File.php/function/File%3A%3AgetFileUri/8.8.x

Comment: $attachment = $entity->get('field_attachment')->getFileUri(); results in error saying : Call to undefined method Drupal\media\Entity\Media::getFileUri(). Not sure what I'm missing

Comment: If it is a media entity, you need to get the file/image field off that entity before calling that.

Comment: $file_uri = file_create_url($entity->field_attachment->entity->getFileUri()); working for me. Now, I'm trying to make it an array to get more than 1 selected view row